# Why does checkbox size look different in Chrome but same in Edge?

Tags: html, google-chrome, checkbox, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

I have created a table with striped rows in bootstrap 4. One of the table columns have html check-boxes.

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhptyn6x/2/)

If you open it on Google Chrome, the Default check-boxes in rows with darker background colour look smaller in size compared to the one in white background colour whereas if you open it on Microsoft Edge or Opera Mini, they look the same size. Is there a difference or just my illusion? Is this a bug on Edge or Chrome or is there a way to have a congruent behavior across all browsers?

The above behaviour is not observed when all rows have the same background colour.

Also, a way around could be to use create a custom checkbox as shown in the same fiddle.

All I have is

```
<some code>
<tr class="bg-primary">
<td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Check1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Check2">
</td>
</tr>
<some code>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's all about how colors and your eyes work. Bright colors always seem bigger than dark ones.

In Chrome, the native checkbox is darker than Opera's and Edges' one.

So if you look to the native checkbox in the dark background in Chrome they will look smaller. And in the white background they will appear better.

Besides that, you have the border color, which looks like the background, so it masks a little.

The checkboxes are the same size.

Comment: To confirm this is an optical illusion, you can literally take a ruler and measure both boxes. Or you can take a screenshot, and zoom in to count the pixels. (Zooming right in the browser won't work as it auto-scales the checkboxes.)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually an issue with CSS itself, which don't allow personalisation on checkbox (same issue with file share). So each browser have his own display of checkbox without any "clean" solution to normalize it.

So there is a "dirty" solution to do it :

- Set your checkbox invisible
- Create a button with 2 appearance (checked and not checked)
- Use JS to enable and disable the checkbox on click

With this you will have a button acting as checkbox (visually) with JS and piloting the real checkbox used in your form.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because in first table row element  you are including a class  that changes color in background, maybe it's kinda optical illusion what make's you perceive one of the checkboxes bigger than the other.

Try to include that class in both  or delete on both, like this:

```
<some code>
<tr class="bg-primary">
<td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Check1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="bg-primary">
<td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Check2">
</td>
</tr>
<some code>
```